# Google Maps Embed API show pin with center lat lon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Embed API like this
with lat and lon

```
<iframe
      width="600"
      height="450"
      frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=45.46038,9.18259&zoom=14&maptype=roadmap" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

is there a way to get also a pin like I get with this

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of Google Maps Embed API, the [view mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#view_mode) that you are using on your first request returns a map with no markers or direction.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=YOUR_API_KEY&center=45.46038,9.18259&zoom=14&maptype=roadmap
```

In order to show the pin, change your mode in to [place mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode), because the Place mode displays a map pin at a particular place or address, such as a landmark, business, geographic feature, or town.

Here is the code that I use to show the pin.

```
<iframe
width="600"
height="450"
frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=45.46038,9.18259&zoom=14&maptype=roadmap" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```